# React Native - How to navigate to main body after IntroSliders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to integrate opening app intro sliders to my app, but failing to connect the points to get from the intro to my main app body.

[The library i'm using](https://github.com/Jacse/react-native-app-intro-slider) says use 'react-native-app-intro-slider' as such, where an `_onDone()` function is called to finish the intro and show the 'real' app:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  _onDone = () => {
    // User finished the introduction. Show "real" app
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AppIntroSlider
        slides={slides}
        onDone={this._onDone}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

With the main body of my app (it works when I run it without the intro-slider addition) being this:

```
render() {
    const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <Card key={index}>
                       [[there's stuff here omitted]]
                    </Card>
                )
              });
    return (
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                  <CardStack>
                   {contents}
                  </CardStack>
                </View>
              );
```

How can I get this to render after the introslider? Do I put all that inside the _onDone() function? (this doesn't work). Or is there a way write `_onDone` so that after the  component, the regular part of the main app would proceed to go as before?

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  _onDone = () => {
    // Something that lets me pass onto the main part of my app
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AppIntroSlider
        slides={slides}
        onDone={this._onDone}
      />

// The main body of the app that I want React to get to after the <AppIntroSlider> component.

    const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <Card key={index}>
                  [[there's stuff here omitted]]
                </Card>
            )
          });
      return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
              <CardStack>
                {contents}
              </CardStack>
            </View>
          );
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are u using some sort of router?

Comment: @Panther -- no.. is that something necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using a navigation library, I would suggest to simply use state:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    showRealApp: false
  }
}

_onDone = () => {
  this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
}
render() {
  if (this.state.showRealApp) {
    const contents = collection.map((item, index) => (
      <Card key={index}>
        {...}
      </Card>
    ));
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <CardStack>
          {contents}
        </CardStack>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return <AppIntroSlider slides={slides} onDone={this._onDone}/>;
  }
}
```

You can also consult issue [#18](https://github.com/Jacse/react-native-app-intro-slider/issues/18#issuecomment-358032248) on the react-native-app-intro-slider repo.